# Samsung Galaxy J1 stuck on "Downloading. Do not turn off target" screen

Tags: samsung, boot

I have an old Samsung Galaxy J1 that would turn on and then go to a screen with some cogs that said 'Optimizing Android', but whenever it was just about to finish, it would shut down.

I got a new battery for it and tried to force restart it, but now it is stuck on a screen that says 'Downloading', 'Do not turn off target'. It has been like this for 4 days now.

How can I fix it?

Comment: OP's follow-up question: [Samsung Galaxy J1 shuts down after "Optimizing Android" on startup](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/253822/44325)

Answer (score 1):

'Downloading' 'Do not turn off target' is a boot mode used for flashing the phone with ROM/firmware, known as Download mode or Odin Mode. It does not actually download anything until you connect it to a PC and flash it with Odin3.
You can exit Download mode by pressing the same key combination required to enter Download mode, usually Home + Volume Down + Power buttons, for several seconds.

If the phone returns to Download mode again, it's due to an emergency situation, indicating that the ROM is corrupted and unable to boot. In such cases, find the appropriate stock ROM for your region/carrier and flash it. Please note that this process will factory reset your phone.

Comment: also check your phone model [SM-J100M](https://samfw.com/firmware/SM-J100M) or [SM-J120H](https://samfw.com/firmware/SM-J120H). use Odin v3.10 or older