# Samsung Galaxy J1 shuts down after "Optimizing Android" on startup

Tags: samsung, boot, operating-system, shutdown

I have an old Samsung Galaxy J1 20W that when it restarts, it goes to the 'Optimizing Android', and whenever it gets to '13 out of 13', it just shuts down and won't turn on again unless I take out the battery and put it back in.

Is there any hope for it? Or is it done for good?

Comment: You could try to reinstall the original firmware (there are some tools and websites available which allow to download the full OTA images) and/or perform a factory reset.

Comment: Where would I find the firmware?

Comment: For Samsung devices sammobile has AFAIR has the firmwares.